# Can you explain the logic behind degrees of freedom for interaction effect in multi-factorial ANOVA?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, degrees-of-freedom

I am currently trying to build intuition for two-factor ANOVA by doing some simulation in Python, and some things are hard for me to parse.

I have an ANOVA with 4 levels of one factor and 3 levels of the other one, which leaves us with 6 degrees of freedom for calculating the Mean Squared Distance of Interaction Effect

I can't figure out why the sum of squared distances of 12 combinations of factors scaled by the sample size EXACTLY follows a chi2 distribution with 6 degrees of freedom. I get that the parameters used in calculating each term for the sum of squared distances are not independent and there's some co-dependency going on, but how they are related is beyond me.

Videos on YouTube on the subject of degrees of freedom are all misleading.

Comment: Do you want an intuitive type of answer, or the math behind it?